# format bash variable for command

Tags: bash, shell

From my bash shell I would like to call a program n times with a different numbered parameter, which has to be in a fixed format like "%02i"

One way would be:

```
for ((i=23; i<42;i++)); do 
    sh ../myprogram `printf "%02i\n" $i`
done
```

Is there a way to improve the `printf..` part? I believe this might be a performance bottleneck with more files and makes the line less readable than a built-in function (especially when condensed to a one-liner).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Bash, `printf` is provided by the shell (see [the bash(1) manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash), search for "printf"), so you don't even have the (minimal) overhead of `fork()` and `exec()` to execute a separate command -- unless you run it from within backticks. Bash's built-in printf lets you assign the output to a given variable with the `-v` argument; your script fragment could be rewritten as:

```
for ((i=23; i<42;i++)); do 
    printf -v ii "%02i\n" $i
    sh ../myprogram $ii
done
```

I'm not sure I'd consider that more readable than the original.

The most resource-intensive part of your script fragment is calling your other shell script; I wouldn't worry about the overhead of calling printf unless further evidence indicates otherwise.

*edited to add the difference between backticks and direct execution*

Comment: The printf is in backticks, which presumably means it needs to spawn a sub-shell to handle it.

Comment: Ah, you're right. (A few quality minutes with strace proved that backticks spawn a child process.) Updating answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your number already has 2 decimal places. Why do you need to use printf then? If i remember correctly (haven't got a shell for testing here), it just pads the number up to 2 decimals when used with those flags. Personally, i like xargs:

```
seq 23 42 | xargs -n1 sh ../myprogram
```

You can use the `-w` argument for `seq`, which pads the numbers with zeros if necessary, so they have all the same width.

It turns out `seq` is linux specific. Thanks for Dave in the comments for figuring it out (his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458972/format-bash-variable-for-command#459070)). Use `printf` directly, without a loop:

```
printf '%02i\n' {23..42} | xargs -n1 sh ../myprogram
```

I like to use `xargs`, because it allows easily running your commands in parallel up to some limit, can pass more than one number at once and allows other flexible options. Like Dave, i recommend you to drop the `sh` from it, and place it into your shell script, as first line instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
.....
```

Then just execute your stuff as

```
printf '%02i\n' {23..42} | xargs -n1 ../myprogram
```

This is more generic, and allows your script also to be called by the `exec` C library calls (at least in Linux, that's the case).

Comment: seq appears to be Linux specific.  The BSD superset of seq is jot.

Answer (score 1):

FYI: A completely different solution:

```
jot -w "%02i" - 23 42 | xargs -n 1 ../myprogram
```

This has the performance downside of calling [jot](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=jot&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.1-RELEASE&format=html) (standard since 4.2BSD so all the BSD derivatives have it, but a quick look shows that this basic wonderful tool appears to be lacking from the Linux distributions I looked at).  **Edit**: Linux (at least Red Hat) appears to have a subset of jot's features in a command called [seq](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=seq&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Red+Hat+Linux%2Fi386+9&format=html) (thanks to litb's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458972/format-bash-variable-for-command#459041) for this info).

This has the benefit of working in non-bash shells as well (unlike what some people think, there is more than one shell in active use and shell-agnostic solutions are generally a good idea).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
for i in {23..42} ; do
    sh ../myprogram $i
done
```

Numbers between 23 and 42 are always going to be in %02i format.

If you absolutely must format, then

```
for i in {23..42} ; do
    printf "%02i\n" | xargs -n1 sh ../myprogram $i
done
```

Substitutes the overhead of spawning xargs for the overhead of spawning the subshell for the backticks.  I have no idea which is more efficient.

Comment: Presumably that was an example (albeit perhaps a bad one).

Comment: Actually, I only wrote that answer to show off the {n..m} list, which is probably more efficient that the for loop he posted.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
seq -w 23 41
```

This will fillup with leading 0 automatically to needed size

or:

```
seq -f "%02g" 1 29
```

This will format to exact 2 digits.

So complete command would be:

```
for i in `seq -f "%02g" 23 41`; do 
    sh ../myprogram $i
done
```